# Google Colab User Actvity

Tags: google-colaboratory, user-activity

Is there a way to check how many people are using google colab at the same time you are?

I tried to look up via google and other sources and couldn't find any concrete information regarding the number of Users using the GPU at once.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to view overall Colab usage.

You could add analytics reporting to individual notebooks using Python APIs like this one:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

But, that would only report usage for users of a given notebook who execute code rather than users of Colab overall.